# How to get the highlight widget from flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart

As title, if the user hover a UI element, it will highlight on flutter web, I would like to know how do I know which element is being hover and highlighted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To select text, [simply use the `selectableText` widget.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSU3ZXOs6hc)

As for hovers, its supposed to be under the guestures widget, but there are work arounds.

[Work around 1](https://gist.github.com/efortuna/af7c2d52ff56de52f5652548715da10a)

[Work around 2](https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/1132)